# How can I loop though columns by name in an SSIS Script component?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, system.reflection

I'm loading a pipe delimited flat file into a staging table. During the load process an SSIS script component performs some operations on a row. It may set a flag in one field based on values in another field, add a prefix to certain columns, or apply formatting.  For example, if a date is missing, the field is assigned to a default date.  (if Row.EndDate_isNull then Row.EndDate = defaultDate)

These scripts become cumbersome when the same transformation needs to be applied to a series of rows. For example, a medical record file can describe each of 9 diagnoses with three fields: Diagnosis01_Date, Diagnosis01_Code, Diagnosis01_System....Diagnosis09_Date, Diagnosis09_Code, Diagnosis09_System.

I want to use a loop to perform the operations over each of the 9 groups of 3 fields, instead of writing the same operation 9 times.

If I were dealing with a collection in VB, for example, I'd write something like this in in the Input0_ProcessInputRow sub:

```
For i = 1 to 9
   row.("Diagnosis0"+ i + "_Date").Value = diagnosisDate
   row.("Diagnosis0"+ i + "_System").value = "ICD10"
next i
```

In the SSIS object model, however, the columns are exposed as properties of Input0Buffer and I can't find a way to use a variable to refer to them. So, how *can* I create a loop that operates on columns by name in an SSIS script component?

Edit:   I found the following sources, especially the first two,  to be helpful while I was doing my research on this problem. It seems like there should be a solution using system.reflection, but I just don't know .NET well enough to figure it out.

http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2007/10/21/address-columns-generically-in-a-script-task/

http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2007/06/02/xml-destination-script-component/

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2010/12/do-something-for-all-columns-in-your.html

http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2011/05/iterating-over-columns-in-ssis-script.html

http://bidn.com/blogs/MikeDavis/ssis/1800/ssis-for-each-column-in-a-data-flow

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edbac1df-f05f-40db-820a-e009fae201a4/using-script-destination-object-to-create-and-write-to-new-text-file?forum=sqlintegrationservices&forum=sqlintegrationservices

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/757d11c8-8ad4-4021-a959-1d13c8dfdaa7/how-to-run-a-loop-for-all-columns-in-script-component-input-column-collection-for-each-row?forum=sqlintegrationservices

[How can I get the column Value in Script Component in SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434886/how-can-i-get-the-column-value-in-script-component-in-ssis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Simple Workaround

You can store columns name in a `List(of string)` using loops , and use `Row.GetType().GetProperties()` to manipulate columns dynamically.

**Example:**

*Note: You have to import `System.Reflection` , `System.Linq` and `System.Collections.Generic` libraries*

```
Dim lstDateColumns as new List(of string)
Dim lstSystemColumns as new List(of string)

For i = 1 to 9
    lstDateColumns.Add("Diagnosis0" & i.toString() & "_Date")
    lstSystemColumns.Add("Diagnosis0" & i.toString() & "_System")
Next


For each  dataColumn as PropertyInfo in Row.GetType().GetProperties()


    If lstDateColumns.Contains(dataColumn.Name) Then

                 dataColumn.SetValue(Row, diagnosisDate, Nothing)

     ElseIf lstSystemColumns.Contains(dataColumn.Name) Then

                dataColumn.SetValue(Row, "ICD10", Nothing)

     End IF
Next
```

And you can filter over columns names from the lists

```
    Dim lstDateColumns As New List(Of String)
    Dim lstSystemColumns As New List(Of String)

    For i As Integer = 1 To 9
        lstDateColumns.Add("Diagnosis0" & i.ToString() & "_Date")
        lstSystemColumns.Add("Diagnosis0" & i.ToString() & "_System")
    Next

    For Each dataColumn As PropertyInfo In Row.GetType().GetProperties().Where(Function(x) lstDateColumns.Contains(x.Name))

        dataColumn.SetValue(Row, diagnosisDate, Nothing)

    Next


    For Each dataColumn As PropertyInfo In Row.GetType().GetProperties().Where(Function(x) lstSystemColumns.Contains(x.Name))

        dataColumn.SetValue(Row, "ICD10", Nothing)

    Next
```

**References**

- https://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/ssis-global-replace-for-all-columns-using-a-script-component/

Comment: I see that this gets me part way there--It will allow me to loop through my fields because they're in the list.  Is there a way to avoid iterating over all of the columns in the source?

Comment: Is my worry about the overhead of looping through all columns unjustified?

Comment: You're right. I think you can filter on column name using linq. Few moments and i'll update

Comment: @DataWriter i updated my answer, remember to imports `System.Linq`  library to use `Where` function

Comment: This is fantastic. I had to change the .net framework to enable linq, since I'm on SSIS2008, and it worked first try.  Thank you!

Comment: Can I declare the lists as private module-level variables and add the column names in the event Public Overrides Sub PreExecute() so that I only have to assign the values once once for the package execution, instead of doing it for each row when Input0_ProcessInputRow fires?

Comment: Yes,Your approach is better. @DataWriter

Comment: And, if I can ask one final question: how can I use dataColumn.GetValue to work with a given column's value inside of the loop?   "Select case dataColumn.GetValue(Row)" doesn't work.

Comment: I need to check it. And i will reply. @DataWriter

Comment: It looks like it's dataColumn.GetValue(row,Nothing)

Comment: @DataWriter i think it is as you said `dataColumn.GetValue(Row,Nothing)`